# Как безопасно организовать проверку смс-кода

Tags: java, android

У меня есть приложение в котором работает проверка номера телефона по смс-коду.
Как безопасно работать с этим кодом?

Сейчас у меня реализовано следующим образом:

- На стороне клиента генерируется рандомный 6-x значный код и вместе с введённым телефоном передается на мой сервер для дальнейшей отправки смс
- Сгенерированный ранее код передается в следующий класс, где сверяется с тем что ввел пользователь

Я не совсем уверен что это безопасно.. Можете подсказать как это правильно делается?

Comment: а зачем код генерить на клиенте? пользователь ввел номер телефона, который запросом отпраляется на бек. на беке он проходит валидацию, после чего бек отправляет смс со сгенерированным кодом (который сам бек и сгенерировал). смс приходит, пользователь вводит полученный код, запрос с введенным кодом летит на бек, бек сверяет коды. бинго!

Comment: Спасибо за решение! Я думал об этом но немного не понимаю как реализовать проверку кода на бэке.

Comment: не совсем понял, в чем именно сложность проверки кода на беке? вы его сгенерили на беке, следовательно, вы его знаете. устанавливаете таймаут (время действия кода), ждете запроса с клиента с этим самым кодом и просто сверяете код, который сами же сгенерили и отправили в смс с кодом, который прилетел в запросе с клиента

Comment: Понял, спасибо!